# IE bug with video loaded in colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically loading videos in colorbox and everything works fine, except IE is showing video which is inside hidden div. How to manage that?

This is my colorbox call:

```
$('#play-button').colorbox({
        inline : true,
        opacity: 0.6,
        width  : 920,
        height : 690,
        top    : 160,
        href   : "#video-player-lightbox"
    }).data('css-class','soccer-lightbox');
```

and this is my html structure:

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="video-player-lightbox">
        <h2>Goals player</h2>
        <?php echo print_full_player( ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

```
<div style="display:none;visibility:hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a flash video player?  Are you sure that the window mode for the video in IE is set to `opaque` or `transparent` instead of `window`, `direct` or `gpu`?  If you aren't using some sort of script to generate your flash code, you probably have some sort of embed tag in object tag or object tag within object tag for embedding the flash player and you have to set the `wmode` for both.